# Analytic Elements for a group of Isometries in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras

Why can an analytic element with respect to translations along a timelike direction not belong to a local algebra in a Haag Araki theory? I know the claim is true, but is there any concise justification?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a concrete context. I'm guessing with local algebra you mean a quasi-local $C^*$-algebra over bounded open subsets of Minkowski space (with orthogonality being given by spacelike seperation). When is an element "analytic with respect to translations along a time-like direction"?

Comment: When I refer to local algebras I mean algebras associated with open bounded regions of Minkowski spacetime.

Comment: The image doesn't really clarify a lot. What text is it from? The notation reminds me of Bratteli and Robinson

Comment: You are right it is from vol. I of B-R I do not remember now the exact page number to provide full citation.